# How to write code to pick the selected EMail address from phone book to send E-mail from my iphone application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, abpeoplepickerview

I have implemented send Email code using MFmailComposer...

**it's FINE  but the problem is in *picking the Email address of the recipient*** .

***i wan t to get the Email address from the address book contacts.***

How retrieve this any help please

i have implemented a ABPeoplePickerNavigationController delegate methods for contacts it gives

```
- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker
      shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person
                                property:(ABPropertyID)property
                              identifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifier 
{
    if (property == kABPersonPhoneProperty) 
    {
        ABMultiValueRef emails = ABRecordCopyValue(person, property);
        CFStringRef phonenumberselected = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(emails, identifier);
        CFStringRef emailLabelSelected = ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(emails, identifier);
        CFStringRef emailLabelSelectedLocalized = ABAddressBookCopyLocalizedLabel(ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(emails, identifier));
        NSLog(@"\n EmailValueSelected = %@ \n EmailLabelSelected = %@ \n \EmailLabeSelectedlLocalized = %@", phonenumberselected, emailLabelSelected, emailLabelSelectedLocalized);

        recipientField.text = (NSString *)emails; //Crashes but accepts 'phonenumberselected'

       NSLog(@" emails###:%@...  phonenumberselected%@...  emailLabelSelected %@.... emailLabelSelectedLocalized %@")

    //emails###: ABMultiValueRef 0x80b7bc0 with 1 value(s) //**Log output Displyas like this**


        [ self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES ];
        return NO;
    }   
    return YES;
```

### }

***`How to write code to pick the selected EMail address from phone book`***

Comment: `MFmailComposeViewController` allows user to select recipient, so why would you implement it?

Answer (score 1):

Following link is use for the implemented code where the fetch the email address from contact and add into our array,

[Reference Link](https://github.com/eaigner/COPeoplePickerViewController)

Comment: Oops! Google Chrome could not find file Reference Link